# Are complex eigenvalues special?

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've noticed that complex eigenthings are treated as a whole separate topic to real eigenthings (I say things to mean values and vectors).

I see no reason for this distinction, yes it makes the geometric interpretations different.... but it's not like one one has to do a completely different method to find them.

So my question is should I go read about complex eigenvalues in great detail, like they are a new topic, or just plough into it.

My situation is that there's some homework and I'm thinking "is this actually different to what I know already?" I am sure of course there is value to studying them and I shall, but is it a "big deal" is a question that reads "find the complex eigenvectors and values" different in any significant way from "find the eigenvectors and values" (assumed to be real)

Sorry this is a bit of a null question, I just - I want to know if I've missed something.

Addendum:

I've thought about it and there's no reason the definitions I know already to only work with real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are complex roots of polynomials special? Yes, they are, in a sense that a polynomial may have no real roots, or less of them than its degree (even if its coefficients are all real!), while [it will have exactly the same number of complex roots (counted with their multiplicity) as is its degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

In the same way, complex eigenvalues are "special". A real matrix may have no real eigenvalues. For example, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has eigenvalues $\pm i$. However, when the matrix is real, its complex eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs (if $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue, then $\overline{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue), which also correspond to some matrices of order $2$, which is why the [real Schur decomposition](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf) has the form it has.

This is not very different from the fact that each real polynomial can be written in form

$$\prod_k q_k(x) \prod_k l_k(x),$$

where $l_k$ are linear polynomials, while $q_k$ are irreducible quadratic polynomials.

This is not really surprising, given that eigenvalues are the roots of a polynomial $\det(A - \lambda{\rm I})$.

Personally, I prefer doing everything with complex numbers and then, if needed, restricting that to the real vector space.

I leave it to you to decide if this makes complex eigen*things* special or not.